# Как правильно писать название коньяка Hennessy?

Tags: прописная-строчная, кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно записать название коньяка Hennessy, например, в предложении:

```
Он налил себе рюмку "Хеннесси".
```

Нужны ли здесь кавычки и прописная буква? Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В кавычки заключаются названия товарных знаков, условные названия продуктовых, парфюмерных и др. товаров, **в том числе алкогольных напитков.**
При употреблении в качестве торговой марки названия продовольственных товаров пишутся с прописной буквы в кавычках:
вафли «Сливочные», карбонад «Любительский», сыр «Моцарелла», соус «Тартар», ликер «Бейлис», вино «Божоле Нуво», вермут «Чинзано Бьянко», коньяк «Хеннесси».

Не заключаются в кавычки написанные **латиницей** названия:
сок Global Village, пиво Staropramen, оливки Oro Verde, коньяк Hennessy, джинсы Armani.

*Усмехнувшись, Долгорукий погладил кошку, запрыгнувшую на подоконник, и **налил себе рюмку «Хеннесси»...*** (Э. Тополь. Свободный полет одинокой блондинки)

*— Алиска, иди домой, я сегодня что-то не форме, извини, если обидел… За твои глаза, — он залпом **опрокинул рюмку Hennessy XO*** (З. Виноградская. Счастлива по собственному желанию).

[Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)

Comment: Моцарелла-то почему?! Это вид молочного продукта, как кефир, йогурт, масло и т.д.

Comment: Я не большой знаток сыров, но Росконтроль пишет об одном из них так: **сыр "Моцарелла" Bonfesto**. https://roscontrol.com/product/sir-bonfesto-motsarella/ Вы считаете мой ответ неверным? Тогда надо спорить с Грамотой.

Comment: Не считаю, просто удивлен. Но Росконтроль я бы в качестве примера не учитывал. Они сами не могут решить, как правильно, там дальше есть моцарелла без кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

**Он налил себе рюмку "Хеннесси".**

(Hennessy [ɛnˈsiː] — один из старейших и известнейших французских коньячных домов).

**Так пишут часто, но правильно ли это?** Об этом можно узнать у Розенталя.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=27#pp27

1. **Общеизвестные названия** сортов вин пишутся со строчной буквы: бордо, бургундское, кагор, кахетинское, мадера, мускат, портвейн, рислинг, токай, херес, цимлянское, цинандали, шампанское.

**ПАС:** Примечание. Названия сортов вин, минеральных вод и др. напитков, **ставшие именами нарицательными**, пишутся без кавычек со строчной буквы, напр.: портвейн, шампанское, мадера, кагор, рислинг, кока-кола, ессентуки-17.

**В специальной литературе** названия марок вин пишутся с прописной буквы: портвейн Айгешат, шампанское Абрау-Дюрсо, десертное вино Цинандали.

2. **Условные названия вин** заключаются в кавычки, первое слово пишется с прописной буквы: вино «Солнечная долина», венгерское вино «Бычья кровь», шампанское «Надежда».

**Кажется, ни одно из правил однозначно не подходит,** используется "гибридное" написание "Хеннесси". Это что-то среднее между специальной литературой и условным названием. Но ведь в нашем случае мы имеем название торгового дома (его нельзя сравнить с условным названием конкретной марки вина), и литература у нас не специальная, а художественная.  **Поэтому такое написание наименее правильное, но в то же время самое частотное.**

Кстати, в  теме наименований  есть еще одна форма письма ― **строчная буква и кавычки** (по образцу клубника "виктория"). Это название является уже **нарицательным, но еще сохраняет признак условности.**

**Вот эти три формы и можно встретить в художественной литературе.**

Примеры:

(1) Подойдя к несгораемому шкафу, он достал из него **бутылку «Хеннесси»** и пару не особо чистых граненых стаканов. [Виктор Пелевин. Generation «П» (1999)]

(2) ― Значит, коньячку… **хеннесси** есть?.. Прекрасно! [Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга третья. Книга Перемен (1998)]

С меня хватит! Я выбираю **хеннесси!**  [Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга первая. Изгой (1998)]

(3) ― **Два «хеннесси».** Ой, извините, добрый день! [Ирина Телицына. (1997) // «Столица», 1997.08.12]

Что касается литературы **специальной или просто тематической,** то там пишут так:

Коньяк **Хеннесси** входит в четверку так называемых Великих коньячных домов и  на сегодняшний день является бесспорным мировым лидером в своей области.

Все виды **Хеннесси** содержат в себе 40% алкоголя. Исключением из правил стал коллекционный **Hennessy Ellipse**, чья крепость составляла 43,5 градуса.

Источник: https://vzboltay.com/alcohol/brandy/479-hennessy.html